# divide by arrays containing zeros, python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, zero, divide

I want to make a calculation using two arrays, containing values from 0 to 255. Since i cannot divide by zero I used the following code to circumvent this problem.

```
#creation of the two arrays by reading pixel values of an image
data2 = band2.ReadAsArray(0,0,cols,rows)
data3 = band3.ReadAsArray(0,0,cols,rows)

#create array to mark all zero values
mask = numpy.greater((data2+data3), 0)

#do calculation with all values >0 or else assign them -99
ndvi = numpy.choose(mask,(-99, (data3-data2)/(data2 + data3)))
```

However, i still recieve the error: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
where is my mistake? It shouldnt still want to divide by zero, should it?

When I change the last line to this it works, but my data is not accurate anymore.

```
ndvi = numpy.choose(mask,(-99, (data3-data2)/(data2 + data3 + 1)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition for division by zero is `(data2+data3)==0`, so the following should work:

```
mask = numpy.not_equal((data2+data3), 0)
ndvi = numpy.choose(mask,(-99, (data3-data2)/(data2 + data3)))
```

Another way to do this is:

```
mask = (data2+data3)==0
ndvi = np.zeros(data2.shape)
ndvi[  mask ] = -99
ndvi[ ~mask ] = ((data3-data2)/(data2+data3))[ ~mask ]
```

Comment: I dont really understand the second code, but it works fine. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: to give you more details about the second one, `~mask` is equal to `np.logical_not(mask)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about getting an "Infinity" where you divide by zero, you can suppress numpy's warning using `numpy.seterr(zero='ignore')` at the top of your code.

Or, if you only want to use it for a specific section (say in a function), do `numpy.seterr(zero='ignore')` at the top of your function, then `numpy.seterr(zero='warn')` at the end of the function.

This way you don't have to worry about making masks to avoid a warning.

Comment: This does not work in Python 2.7. The correct code is:
    numpy.seterr(divide='ignore')
and
    numpy.seterr(devide='ignore')

Comment: @MoTSCHIGGE I'm sure you meant `numpy.seterr(divide='ignore')` and `numpy.seterr(divide='warn')`, correct?  I'm not sure what  `numpy.seterr(devide='ignore')` would do.

Comment: Of course. Sorry for that. The correct keyword is "divide" and it accepts 'ignore' and 'warn' to turn the error message off or on.